# How to restrict http access to video files?

Tags: php, http

I want to only let "right" people watch those videos. In other words, only registered users that are allowed (by other users, ie, friends) should see videos.  I have a hard retriction for cpu usage in my shared environment, so I can't use things like php's readfile.

Answer (score 2):

Stream through PHP using `readfile`, as you mention. Just set a cookie with a session ID when someone logs in and check it before you start streaming the video, and don't bother if they're not authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/

Answer (score 0):

It must be http streaming any way.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Samir Talwar way to go. But if this is too CPU intensive (I'm not really sure of this), you can go with apache and use a backend PHP script that will allow or deny access upon user cookie state.

But have you access to apache conf in your shared env ?

If so, you can look at apache [urlrewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) guide, in "Extended Redirection" section.